# What are the possible causes of head tilt in rabbits?

Tags: health, rabbits, injury

I have heard a lot about head tilt in rabbits.  What causes head tilt? What are the treatments and/or prognosis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far is I found the possible causes are:

- Middle/inner ear infection (otitis media /interna) - treated with anitbiotics - success not sure
- Stroke (cerebrovascular accidents) - lots of care needed - acupuncture maybe helpful
- Trauma - can be treated with anti-inflammatory - succesful if trauma not severe
- Cancer (neoplasia) - did not find much, but it's cancer
- Cervical muscle contraction - only temporary
- Encephalitozoonosis - parasite - treatment not mentioned
- Cerebral larva migrans - no known cure
- Intoxication - depending on the toxin, vet needs to decide
- an abscess - needs to be removed with surgery
- Meningitis

The treatments do depend on the cause ([Read more](https://rabbit.org/journal/3-8/head-tilt.html)). But

> While many cases of head tilt can be successfully treated, others cannot.[...]Regardless of the cause, sometimes a rabbit who survives will be left with a slight head tilt for the rest of his life.

**References**

- [Head Tilt: Causes and Treatment](https://rabbit.org/journal/3-8/head-tilt.html)
- [Head Tilt (Wry Neck) in Rabbits](https://articles.extension.org/pages/33031/head-tilt-wry-neck-in-rabbits)
- [Head Tilt in Rabbits](https://www.thesprucepets.com/head-tilt-in-rabbits-4021111)

Answer (score -2):

One reason could be the daily drinking from water bottles and so caused habituation to a false head position:

> Studies have shown that a rabbit with access to both a water bowl and a water bottle will prefer the bowl. It’s much easier to drink out of, because the water doesn’t come out one drop at a time. **Also, a bottle forces the rabbit to tilt the head up in an unnatural position, making it highly uncomfortable.** Even though nothing can fall into a bottle and soil the water, it is much more difficult to clean, so bacteria and algae will often develop and soil any fresh water that gets added immediately.

[bunnyapproved.com](https://bunnyapproved.com/water-bowl-and-bottle-options-for-rabbits/)

**Edit:** It is not a chief cause, nor the single cause for head tilt. But I think it could be the most common and one that could be easy avoided.

Comment: Your source and your conclusion have nothing in common.  While I am not a fan of water bottles, there is zero chance that turning your head to drink is going to cause your head to get stuck in a turned posistinl Everyone lifts their feet to walk, when was the last time you saw someone with one foot stuck in the air?

Comment: If you walk with not fitting footwear you can earn a postural deformity too... Walking is a normal movement for humans, drink with the head up is for birds, not for rabbits. I do not say, it is the chief cause, or that I have all causes in my answer, but it was the first cause in my mind and a widespread too.